Update Sales cloud object value from Data Cloud
Scenario:

Snowflake has Item object which has LastActivatedDate field.
Item object is ingested and mapped to Data Cloud DMO.
Sales Cloud also has Item object with LastActivatedDate field.

Requirement:
If there’s a change in value for Item.LastActivatedDate in Snowflake, the Data Cloud DMO will receive the updated value and I need to update Sales Cloud-Item.LastActivatedDate value from the DMO value.
I cannot implement this using Sales cloud triggered flows due to access restrictions. Is there a way to implement from Data Cloud?
Thanks!
